# WebSphere Liberty BASE transaction failure

Tags: transactions, ejb, websphere-liberty, infinispan, java-ee-8

I have set up the WebSphere Liberty BASE version in a Windows environment and tried to deploy the JavaEE application within this runtime. Here we are facing a transaction failure issue and we suppose this issue is generated due to transaction propagation failure. Here we use javax ejb transactions and Infinispan as the in-memory cache layer.  The issue is the main transaction has not propagated to the caching layer.

Below are the features I have used and my server.xml looks something like the below,

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature> 
        <feature>wasJmsSecurity-1.0</feature> 
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>json-1.0</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<transaction
        totalTranLifetimeTimeout="300s"
        propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout="300s"
        heuristicRetryWait="0"
        acceptHeuristicHazard="false" 
        recoverOnStartup="true"
        waitForRecovery="false"/>
```

Here I'm facing the below issue and can anyone please explain to me how to sort out this transaction failure issue? Also please note that we do not use any remote transaction interface here.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create a transactional context without a valid Transaction instance.
    at org.infinispan.context.impl.TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.createInvocationContext(TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.context.impl.TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.createInvocationContext(TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.java:57)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.lock(CacheImpl.java:995)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.lock(CacheImpl.java:980)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache.lock(EncoderCache.java:307)
```